# limit of factorial divided by sum of factorials

Tags: limits, factorial

I'd like to determine the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ following function:$$f\left(n\right)=\frac{n!}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}k!}.$$The following calculations suggest the answer is 1:
$$
\begin{align*}
f\left(10\right)&\approx0.898682 \\\\
f\left(30\right)&\approx0.966627 \\\\
f\left(70\right)&\approx0.985711.
\end{align*}
$$
But this isn't very satisfying. Any input on how I might proceed in finding this limit would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the limit is $1$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4138492/42969. (Found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f%5Cleft(n%5Cright)%3D%5Cfrac%7Bn!%7D%7B%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7Dk!%7D.%24).)

Comment: @MartinR Great. Thank you for sharing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k!=n!\Bigg[\frac 11 +\frac 1 {n}+ \frac 1 {n(n-1)}+ \frac 1 {n(n-1)(n-2)}+\frac 1 {n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}+\cdots \Bigg]$$ Expanding as series for large values of $n$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k!=n!\Bigg[1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {B_k}{n^k}\Bigg]$$where appear Bell numbers. So, using long division
$$f_n=\frac{n!}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}k!}=1-\frac 1n-\frac 1{n^3}-\frac 2{n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}
   {n^5}\right)$$

Using the above truncated expansion for $n=10$ as you did
$$f_{10}=\frac{2247}{2500}=0.898800$$ to be compared to the exact value
$$f_{10}=\frac{1814400}{2018957}=0.898682$$corresponding to a relative error of $0.013$%.